# new SpeechRecognitionEngine crashes with System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported format

Tags: .net, debugging, windows-7, sapi

I have 2 computers running Windows 7 x64 that crash on this line of code:

var rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

with System.ArgumentException: No recognizer of the required ID found. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported format.

Does anyone have any ideas? Google hasn't helped. I disabled Norton which didn't help.

The code works on most computers, just not these 2.

I've tried messing with the constructor eg Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and "en-US" and have checked my control panel > regional is all en_US.

Many thanks!!

Edit: More code is at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1m1wVPFM however the code pasted above is *all* that is needed to replicate the problem on these 2 troublesome PC's.

On the problematic computer, the built in Windows 7 Ultimate voice recognition software works perfectly. The installed recognizers also appear to be default - just 2 installed; en_GB and en_US. The en_US is the one getting selected (matches user locale).

Comment: More code would help.

Comment: Couple of things come to mind; 1) Audio device can't be instantiated (no audio device installed, or has weird default format); 2) Default SR engine isn't built for en_US.

Comment: Edited question with more info.